# Loading html page on nodeJS won't load until keyboard interrupt

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, localhost

I am new to nodeJS. I am trying to load an index.html page onto my 8080 port and have this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var PORT = 8080;

function home(req, res) {
  if(req.url == '/'){
    fs.readFile('index.html', function read (err, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type' : 'text/html'});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
  });
  }
};

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  home(req, res);
});

server.listen(PORT);
```

I have 3 files in the same directory: index.html, style.css, server.js. I start up the server and the page will not load until after I hit cntrl + c. Why is this?

Comment: Yes, you're missing `res.end()`. Rather than reinventing the wheel though I recommend using [express](https://expressjs.com/) instead.

Comment: Yep, I have added res.end() and the page still will not load.

Comment: Using the code above, including `res.end()`, visiting http://localhost:8080 works fine for me and displays index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written the data to the response, but you have not finished the response. Put `res.end();` after your `res.write` function.

Without this, the browser keeps waiting for more data from the server. When you shut down the server with Ctrl-C, the server closes the connection, and the browser renders what it received.

If you are new to Node, I would recommend looking into something like [Express](https://expressjs.com/), which handles a lot of important things like routing (what URLs go to which pages) for you and will save you a lot more if statements in the future.